# Error: Unexpected BLOCK DATA statement at (1). Why am I getting this error?

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran77 code which has the following lines. I wanted to initialize the variables so I did some changes.

```
COMMON/A1/H(88),AH(88),BV(88),XI(88),PHI(88),ETA(88),RO(88),NL
COMMON/A2/C11(88),C33(88),C44(88),C13(88),G(88),WS,AK
COMMON/B4/NLL,PSO
```

These are the changes I did. But I am getting some compilation errors.

```
BLOCK DATA 
REAL H(88),AH(88),BV(88),XI(88),PHI(88),ETA(88),RO(88),NL
REAL C11(88),C33(88),C44(88),C13(88),G(88),WS,AK
REAL NLL,PSO
COMMON/A1/H(88),AH(88),BV(88),XI(88),PHI(88),ETA(88),RO(88),NL
COMMON/A2/C11(88),C33(88),C44(88),C13(88),G(88),WS,AK
COMMON/B4/NLL,PSO
DATA H /88*0.0/, AH /88*0.0/, BV /88*0.0/, XI /88*0.0/, PHI /88*0.0/, ETA /88*0.0/, RO /88*0.0/, NL /0.0/
DATA C11 /88*0.0/, C33 /88*0.0/, C44 /88*0.0/, C13 /88*0.0/, G /88*0.0/, WS /0.0/, AK /0.0/
DATA NLL /0/, PSO /0.0/
END
```

This is the error for line 1 in 2nd code block:-
`Error: Unexpected BLOCK DATA statement at (1)`

This is the error of line 2 in 2nd code block:-
`Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)` 
This is the error of line 5 in 2nd code block:-
`Error: Unexpected COMMON statement at (1)`

Comment: Please show the [mcve]. What exact changes you did? Was the `BLOCK DATA` there before or not? Did you add it yourself? Where exactly in the code is this. You really have to show the surrounding code, we have to see the context. Show the full code and see also [ask]. Show also your compiler command.

Comment: Previously it was only the 3 COMMON lines. I want to initialize each variables so I decided to put the BLOCK DATA around it. The real code is actually too big and divided into a lot of subroutine, so its not possible to provide the whole code.

Comment: You can't put a `block data` wherever you feel like, any more than you can put `program` wherever you like. We do need to see context ([mre]), but if you have three common statements in a valid place in a program unit and try to put a `block data` in that program unit, yes the compiler is perfectly correct to object.

Comment: Yes, you cannot place `block data` whereever you like, it is a separate program unit. But I repeat, you really have to show the surrounding code, we have to see the context. Get used to always show the already linked minimal reproducible example (MRE) in your questions. It is really important, that's why we have mentioned it seveveral times already.

Answer (score 1):

We can probably the answer the main point. However, to able to do that we have to guess how your actual code loks like. And we should not have to. You cannot normally just post a few lines of code, you must post at least the full program unit that contains them!

So I assume your actual code looks like:

```
   SUBROUTINE SUB

   COMMON/A1/H(88),AH(88),BV(88),XI(88),PHI(88),ETA(88),RO(88),NL
   COMMON/A2/C11(88),C33(88),C44(88),C13(88),G(88),WS,AK
   COMMON/B4/NLL,PSO

   ...
   END
```

or

```
   PROGRAM

   COMMON/A1/H(88),AH(88),BV(88),XI(88),PHI(88),ETA(88),RO(88),NL
   COMMON/A2/C11(88),C33(88),C44(88),C13(88),G(88),WS,AK
   COMMON/B4/NLL,PSO

   ...
   END
```

That means the common blocks are referenced in an existing program unit. You cannot insert `block data` into an existing program unit. It is a separate program unit on its own, it is a special type of subprogram.

You have to create **a new** block data subprogram **outside** of any existing `program`, `subroutine`, `function` or `module`. There may be only one `block data` that initializes a particular common block.